# copy and concatenate values of multiple input boxes in a form to one input field

Tags: jquery, forms, input

copy/duplicate and concatenate values of multiple input boxes to one

I have input fields for street, city, state and zip and the fifth one that says complete address. I am trying to have the full address[concatenated with , as a separator]with all the four aforementioned fields to be filled out on the complete address.

Here's what i have so far. The first one copies (street address) but i need help to concatenate the other fields...

You can Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/subigya/PeVAj/

type="text/javascript">

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $('#street').bind('keypress blur', function() {

        $('#latlongaddress').val($(this).val());

    });

    $('#city').bind('keypress blur', function() {

    ..need help ...

    });

</script>



<form method="post" action="#">

    <div class="formitem">
        <label for="name_of_salon">Name of Salon:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name_of_salon" name="name_of_salon" />
    </div>

    <div class="formitem">
        <label for="street">Street Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="street" name="street" />
    </div>

    <div class="formitem">
        <label for="city"> City:</label>
        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
    </div>

    <div class="formitem">
        <label for="state">State:</label>
        <select name="state" size="1">
            <option value="AK">AK</option>
            <option value="AL">AL</option>
            <option value="AR">AR</option>
            <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
            <option value="CA">CA</option>
            <option value="CO">CO</option>
            <option value="CT">CT</option>
            <option value="DC">DC</option>
            <option value="DE">DE</option>
            <option value="FL">FL</option>
            <option value="GA">GA</option>
            <option value="HI">HI</option>
            <option value="IA">IA</option>
            <option value="ID">ID</option>
            <option value="IL">IL</option>
            <option value="IN">IN</option>
            <option value="KS">KS</option>
            <option value="KY">KY</option>
            <option value="LA">LA</option>
            <option value="MA">MA</option>
            <option value="MD">MD</option>
            <option value="ME">ME</option>
            <option value="MI">MI</option>
            <option value="MN">MN</option>
            <option value="MO">MO</option>
            <option value="MS">MS</option>
            <option value="MT">MT</option>
            <option value="NC">NC</option>
            <option value="ND">ND</option>
            <option value="NE">NE</option>
            <option value="NH">NH</option>
            <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
            <option value="NM">NM</option>
            <option value="NV">NV</option>
            <option value="NY">NY</option>
            <option value="OH">OH</option>
            <option value="OK">OK</option>
            <option value="OR">OR</option>
            <option value="PA">PA</option>
            <option value="RI">RI</option>
            <option value="SC">SC</option>
            <option value="SD">SD</option>
            <option value="TN">TN</option>
            <option value="TX">TX</option>
            <option value="UT">UT</option>
            <option value="VA">VA</option>
            <option value="VT">VT</option>
            <option value="WA">WA</option>
            <option value="WI">WI</option>
            <option value="WV">WV</option>
            <option value="WY">WY</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="formitem">
        <label for="zip">Zip:</label>
        <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" />
    </div>

    <div class="formitem">
        <label for="address_of_salon">Full Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="latlongaddress" name="address" />
    </div>


    <div class="formitem">
        <input type="submit" id="location_submit" name="location_submit" value="Add Location" class="addBtn" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `+` for Javascript concatenation:

```
$('#latlongaddress').val($('#street').val() + ' ' +
                         $('#city').val() + ', ' +
                         $('#state').val() + ' ' +
                         $('#zip').val() );
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dd3ee/).

Answer (score 15):

Just for fun:

```
$('#latlongaddress').val( $('#street,#city,#state,#zip').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(' ') );
```

eykanal's answer is better because it will run quicker and is easier to understand.  Only actually use this for something like `.val($('input')...`

Comment: I believe you need to move the final closing paren to after the end end of the map function so the last line should look like this: `}).get().join(' ');`

Comment: @KyleMit It is fixed now.

Comment: Or instead of using the jQuery selector map() method, using the jQuery utility $.map() method:    `$('#latlongaddress').val($.map($('#street,#city,#state,#zip'), function(latlongaddress){ return $(latlongaddress).val(); }).join(' '));`, either way works. Plus much better using a common class to select the fields than using a single id for each one.

Comment: @user3514092 -- Is there a difference I'm not aware of?

Comment: @zyklus: Note the difference between [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [$(selector).map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/). The first one can be used with any type of array, the second one is special for arrays of selected jquery elements.

Comment: @user3514092 -- Yes, I'm aware of that.  That doesn't explain why you'd bother to re-write it in this case

Comment: @zyklus Just like you said: just for fun.