# Concat 2 textfield values and place it in another text field in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am pretty new to rails please go easy on me n help me out.

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :name %>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :manager %>
 <%= f.text_field :manager %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :concat %>
  <%= f.text_field :concat %>
</div>
```

This is my view i want to merge the values of manager and status and place it in concat field how to do it, i searched a lot but it didn't help.

Comment: You can use Jquery to concat values .

Comment: How do you want to show the `concat` value , I mean as you start typing in the fields of `name` and `manager` OR you have already `name` and `manager` data in those fields and want to show the `concat` value on page load ?

Comment: Use Javascript or Jquery to concatenation two textfields values

Comment: i start typing the name and manager

Comment: @JohnPaul can it be done in rails ? can you please show me an example

Comment: You can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905950/copy-and-concatenate-values-of-multiple-input-boxes-in-a-form-to-one-input-field